# Second Mouse Cursor - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Samsung Odyssey G9

Tags: mouse, display-resolution, samsung

I got a new monitor, the Samsung Odyssey G9. Everything works fine but there is a second mouse pointer on the right side of the monitor which stays there.

Things I've done:

1. Rebooted the PC
2. Changed the resolution (from 5120x1440 to 3840x1080) -> mouse pointer was more far down in the right corner
3. Changed refresh rate of the monitor from 240Hz to 120Hz
4. Disconnected all peripheral devices then boot the PC

Nothing changed. It just stays there.

I searched now for a while on Google about this. Does anyone have an idea?